# Boostrap Modal not popping up when button is pressed

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to have a modal pop up, but when I press the button nothing happens.
Here's the HTMl code so far-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                Well, hello there!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I open the page, a button appears on the top-left corner. Upon pressing it, it dies get highlighted, but nothing happens at all.
Do you have any idea why this is happening, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the problem with your html classes.
[look for Bootstrap 5 model](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

change your html with this or grab from above link

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used bootstrap 4 code instead of bootstrap 5 code, either make all your modals the way bootstrap 5 does it, and you can read it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

or just change bootstrap versions to bootstrap 4

The difference is mostly that in bootstrap 5 you use "data-bs" + something in your attributes instead of just "data-"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script in the head of your html code.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```